# how to make a new Cron job for python scripts to update mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, cron

I'm a newbie to setup a Cron jobs.

i have a prefix directory for my application python on `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prewikka` and i already to new environment for my application python as `PYTHONPATH=$prefix/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prewikka:$prefix/bin/prewikka-httpd`

i already a database MySQL manually :

```
mysql> DESC Prewikka_Crontab;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name     | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| userid   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ext_type | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ext_id   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| base     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| runcnt   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| schedule | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| enabled  | tinyint(11)  | YES  |     | 1       |       |
| error    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

if i launch `prewikka-crontab`, no output appears. when i launch `prewikka-httpd`, i always get the output :

```
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prewikka/history.py", line 102, in <module>
    crontab.schedule("search_history", N_("Search history deletion"), "0 * * * *", _regfunc=history._history_cron, enabled=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prewikka/crontab.py", line 240, in schedule
    self._init_system_job(ext_type, name, schedule, enabled, _regfunc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 91, in inner
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prewikka/crontab.py", line 154, in _init_system_job
    self.add(name, schedule, ext_type=ext_type, enabled=enabled)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prewikka/crontab.py", line 219, in add
    return self.update(None, name=name, schedule=schedule, user=user, ext_type=ext_type, ext_id=ext_id, enabled=enabled)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prewikka/crontab.py", line 209, in update
    return env.db.getLastInsertIdent()
RuntimeError: could not retrieve last insert ID
```

cause i don't have a event scheduler for my client to server side, how i can getting started it with Cron jobs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure it out on this [link](https://www.prelude-siem.org/projects/prelude/wiki/DatabaseOptimisation). a based of the Remove Heartbeats section on that link.

**Step #1** make a `.sh` script :

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

DB_TYPE="mysql" 
DB_HOST="localhost" 
DB_USER="xxxxxx" 
DB_PASS="xxxxxx" 

KEEP_INTERVAL="2 month" 

DATE=$(date -d "now - $KEEP_INTERVAL" +%Y-%m-%d)

preludedb-admin delete heartbeat --criteria "heartbeat.create_time <= $DATE" "type=$DB_TYPE host=$DB_HOST user=$DB_USER pass=$DB_PASS"
```

and make `.sh` as executable.

**Step #2** make a cron job

```
sudo crontab -e
```

add a event scheduler,

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prewikka/crontab.py
*/2 * * * * /path/to/sripts/prewikka.sh
```

restart using `sudo init 6`.

Hope this helps.